# SQL Server Express inserts doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, sql, insert, sql-server-2008-express

In my C# application, I do the following:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstr))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Anfangstierbestand(bestand, jahr, loginid) VALUES (" + bestand + ", " + jahr + ", " + loginid + ");", connection);
    SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select * from Anfangstierbestand;", connection);

    com1.Connection = connection;
    int ferksum = 0;

    com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();

    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader read = com2.ExecuteReader();

    while (read.Read())
    {
        ferksum += Convert.ToInt32(read[2]);
    }

    // MessageBox.Show("Fehler beim Erstellen des Tierbestandes", "Fehler"); }
    MessageBox.Show(ferksum.ToString());
}
```

It's a simple insert to a database. I added `com2` to check, if the insert works.

Unfortunately, the the value of `com2` tells me, that it works, but when I go to the Server Explorer and press Execute SQL, there are no new values.

I don´t know the reason. The code above is just an example, since a few days, no insert works anymore(before, the same code works).

Does anybody know what the reason can be?

**EDIT**:

C#:

```
string connectionstr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Datenbank\\FarmersCalc.mdf;" + "Integrated Security=True;" + "User Instance=true;";
```

**EDIT2:**

Server Explorer:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Farmer´s Calc\Programmierung\WPF\Finanz_WPF\Finanz_WPF\Datenbank\FarmersCalc.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

**EDIT3:**

Here are the columns:

```
id int,
jahr int,
anzahl int,
loginid int
```

**EDIT4:**

Is it possible that it´s a problem that I opened my project with expression blend? Normally, I work with VS 2010...

**EDIT5:**

Even because I can not answer my question(<100 reputations) I write it here:

Shame on me. Some of you were right, it was the wrong database-file. But I´m still wondering, why this happened, because I did not change anything since a few days and before this, it worked!

Thanks to all for helping!

Comment: Maybe you are opening a transaction and never comitting it.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: Are you anywhere near the 4GB or 10GB size-limit -- or is this a small, new DB?  If this happened to me, I'd first check that the DB/server specified in the conn string was in fact the same DB that I was executing the SQL against to check for new values.  Things like that can sometimes happen.

Comment: Too many details missing here. What are the columns data type? Do you insert string data without checking for single quote?

Comment: I already checked both things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using user instances, why? Isn't it possible that the instance you're connecting to in Server Explorer is not the same as the instance where your app is inserting data? What happens when you select data from within the app, does it reflect your insert(s)? It seems to me based on your connection strings that these are two completely different MDF files - they have the same name but they are in different locations.

Answer (score 1):

Is the issue [implicit transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317.aspx)? Do you need to issue a commit of the SQL Insert? If `com2` tells you that it's there then it may only see it since it's in the context of the current SQL transaction.

You should share your connection string for both Server Explorer and your `SqlConnection` (*connectionstr*). Ensure that you setup your Server Explorer connection with [`User Instance=true;`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2010/04/28/fix-sql-server-express-user-instance-connection-error-in-visual-studio-projects.aspx).

Comment: as you can see in my EDIT, my connection string includes `User Instance = true;`

Comment: Since your connection strings are different - maybe you don't need `User Instance=true;` for server explorer. The issue is your connection strings.

Answer (score 1):

As a diagnostic,

```
 connection.Open();
 int n = com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
 // log or show 'n' , the nr of rows affected
```

---

#### Edit, after seeing the connectionstrings:

local db files in `|DataDirectory|\` are very prone to be overwritten by the next run or build command.

Make sure you set them to 'copy never' or 'copy if newer' in the VS Solution explorer.

Comment: `n` tells me that one row is affected

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps somewhere in the callstack above this code, someone has added a TransactionScope.

This would cause the connections to enroll automatically in the transaction, and the connections could see the data inserted via that not-yet-committed transaction.  When the scope is exitted without calling scope.Complete, the transaction gets rolled back and no data is saved.

Comment: I don't think this is a rolled back transaction. The app shows that the data was inserted. I just don't think he's looking in the right place for the new data when he connects with Server Explorer.